# Concat Student name and student ID from Student table in DB2

Tags: db2

I want to concat Student Name and student ID from Student table in DB2 like shown below

Example - Tom(150)

SELECT STUDENT_NAME,CONCAT ( '(', STUDENT_ID ,')') FROM STUDENT;

I tried the above query but getting error

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Always inlcude your platform and version of Db2...

However, I don't believe it matters in this case...

CONCAT is an operator, not a function...

```
-- this returns two columns
SELECT 
  STUDENT_NAME
  , '(' CONCAT STUDENT_ID CONCAT ')' as studentID
FROM
  STUDENT

-- this returns one column
SELECT 
  STUDENT_NAME
    CONCAT '(' CONCAT STUDENT_ID CONCAT ')' as studentID
FROM
  STUDENT
```

Comment: I have a dropdown called student name in the UI, so I need to fetch StudentName(studentid) in the dropdown. When i try the query that you sent, it gives (150) as Student_ID but not Shwetha(150) as Student_ID

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME || '(' || STUDENT_ID || ')' FROM STUDENT;
```